# Unknown tree updater grow_gpu_hist xgboost

Tags: python, xgboost

I have trained `xgboost` model with `GPU('gpu_tree')`. Then saved my model using `pickle`. Now, I'm trying to load that model in Non-GPU machine, but it throwing this error.

```
raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
 xgboost.core.XGBoostError: [16:36:57] /tmp/pip-install-
mqijktew/xgboost/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/xgboost/src/tree/
tree_updater.cc:20:
 Unknown tree updater grow_gpu_hist
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I tried to re-run the exact same model but with `tree_method=hist` and I was able to load the model in a non-gpu machine (rpi4). 
However, the results using `gpu_hist` and `hist` are different, so I was wondering if you were able to reproduce the model you trained with `gpu_hist` in the other machine.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same error the other day, and the problem was that I installed xgboost using conda, and that package does not include GPU components (Have a look at the xgboost.dll, it's only a few MBs).
I then installed xgboost using pip (pip install xgboost), check the size of xgboost.dll, it's now 300+ MB, and this error "Unknown tree updater grow_gpu_hist" disappeared. (xgboost version is 1.5.1)

Not sure whether this would be helpful as I notice the path in your description contains "pip-install"...